# Not receiving telegram verification code in heroku

Tags: python, heroku, telegram, verification, telethon

I write a script and it’s totally working. The problem is when I run in termux (android terminal) this script send me verification code, but when I run in heroku (cloud service) it didn’t accept the verification code.

This is my script:

```
import time
import asyncio
import sys
import random

from telethon import TelegramClient, events, utils, Button

api_id = xxx

api_hash = 'xxx'

sesi_file = 'xxx'

bot = ' '   

with TelegramClient(sesi_file, api_id, api_hash) as client:
   client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message(bot, '/homesx'))
    
@client.on(events.NewMessage(from_users=bot))

async def handler(event):
        pesan = event.raw_text

file = open("homesx.txt","a+")

My script 

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
print(time.asctime(), '-', '
```

Can somebody tell me why I can’t receive a verification code in heroku when i run that script?

Because I received the verif code when run in termux.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is a hosting service not a terminal.There is more than one way to bypass asking of verification code.first one is to use a [session_string](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/sessions.html#string-sessions) and second way is to use [.session](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/sessions.html) file. Check out the full documentation about session [here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/sessions.html#what-are-sessions)

Answer (score -1):

what you can do is to create a session_string and pass it as argument to client object.